# Start Equinox from Windows prompt

Tags: osgi, equinox

I want to start the latest Equinox framework but I'm stuck. I downloaded the latest version and tried to execute the command into windows prompt:

```
C:\equinox\plugins>java -jar org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.100.v20150529-1857.jar -console
```

But nothing happens. Do you know how I can start the framework?

**EDIT**

I downloaded `launchers-win32.win32.x86_64.Mars.zip`

```
C:\equin\eclipse\plugins>java -Declipse.ignoreApp=true -Dosgi.noShutdown=true -Dosgi.console.enable.builtin=true -jar org.eclipse.equinox.la
uncher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar -console
An error has occurred.  See the log file
c:\equin\eclipse\configuration\1435578389939.log

C:\equin\eclipse\plugins>
```

In error log I get this:

```
!SESSION Mon Jun 29 14:44:18 IDT 2015 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2015-06-29 14:44:18.529
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find framework
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.getBootPath(Main.java:1025)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
```

Looks like starting standalone Equinox is very tricky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that sadly the build-in console is removed in equinox 3.10 so the *osgi.console.enable.builtin=true* system property will not work. It was useful when someone wanted to start equinox with a console rapidly, without adding any more bundles.

To use the gogo shell, there are many tutorials. In short:

Download the following artifacts (they are in the zip of Equinox Mars):

- org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.1.100.v20141023-1406.jar
- org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.10.0.v201209301036.jar
- org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.10.0.v201212101605.jar
- org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.10.0.v201209301215.jar

Run the command:

```
java -Declipse.ignoreApp=true -Dosgi.bundles=reference:file:org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.1.100.v20141023-1406.jar@start,reference:file:org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.10.0.v201209301036.jar@start,org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.10.0.v201212101605.jar@start,org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.10.0.v201209301215.jar@start -jar org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.100.v20150529-1857.jar -console -consoleLog
```

Alternatively, you can specify *osgi.bundles* in the *config.ini* file of equinox if there is one.

You can put the necessary jars into a subfolder. In that case, you must use the relative path after *reference:file:*. E.g.: *reference:file:lib/myjar.jar*.

**Edit**

I uploaded two samples (one with config.ini and one without) to here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1GigvByKQkIbFRqbjFvbmNYdk0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Answer is updated ;). Seems that builtin console is removed in 3.10.

Comment: I added the file `plugins\configuration.config.ini` with the following content http://pastebin.com/LtjYdUVH. I see that the jar files are in `plugins` directory. So I started the framework using the command again `C:\equin\eclipse\plugins>java -Declipse.ignoreApp=true -Dosgi.noShutdown=true -Dosgi.console.enable.builtin=true -jar org.eclipse.equinox.la
uncher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar -console` but nothing happens.(This test was performed using launchers-win32.win32.x86_64.Mars.zip)

Comment: Note that I used org.eclise.osgi and not org.eclipse.runtime to start the OSGi environment. I did not use config.ini neither plugins directory as I wanted to have the most minimalistic solution (all configuration in system properties). If you want to pick up the config.ini file, I think you must provide the -configuration argument as well for org.eclipse.osgi jar.

Comment: Can I ask you for a small favor? If you successfully start your downloaded version can you zip it and upload it in dropbox? It will save me a lot of time.

Comment: Yes. The console is working. And to avoid the exception, the builtin console should be switched off. Looking at the source of equinox, I cannot find out, how to switch it on at all. So the solution to avoid the exception: osgi.console.enable.builtin=true

Comment: @BalazsZsoldos after trying out various solutions from the internet (documentation too) for 5 hours, reverse engineering your config files allowed me to solve the problem in ~30mins. Thank you! Btw. remove the `osgi.console.enable.builtin=true` from your example config.ini because it's a bit misleading.

Comment: @Wojtek Thanks for the info. Edited the answer and updated the zip file. The zip file also contains linux shell startup script, too.

Answer (score 1):

There are pre-configured Equinox OSGi Starter Kits available from eclipse itself. They are somehow tricky to find. Open the [Equinox Project Download page](http://download.eclipse.org/equinox/drops/R-Mars-201506032000/index.php) and click on the blue triangle for OSGi starter kits. [image: OSGi starter kits expanded]

Then you can download them for your platform. They have native executables but also valid configuration for "java -jar ..." executions.